# how to set hadoop dfs.replication in java client by class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration or in another way?

Tags: hadoop

how to set hadoop dfs.replication in java client by class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration or in another way?

I use the java Api as client to upload files ,but it always set the dfs.replication to 3,as a result when I use command (hadoop dfsadmin -report) to check the situation,all blocks are under replication factor,because I just have two datanodes to test.

I just want to know how to set hadoop dfs.replication in java client by class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration or in another way? 
 Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the replication is going to be set not by the client connection config but instead by the cluster configuration (???).  Not sure if there is a way to configure file-specific replication which is what I think you are asking about

btw, what percentage of blocks are under-replicated?  can you provide the output of you dfs admin -report command?  That would be helpful

Comment: Under replicated Blocks 21 ,I upload 21 small files to this cluster,one file one block .once I upload a file ,I check the report the Under replicated Blocks will be added by 1.

Comment: I was hoping for more info like a direct copy paste  of the ouput (redacted for your privacy of course) to get an idea of the percentage overall of how many of your blocks are under-replicated

Answer (score 0):

You can type this command at the terminal for setting the replication factor for a file seperately.

> hadoop fs -D dfs.replication=3 -copyFromLocal file.txt /user/myFolder

As for the under-replication that will be taken care by hadoop itself and you will observe that the number of under-replicated blocks keep on changing.

For JAVA API for writing a file with a replication factor refer the following code:

```
 public class Write{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path pt = new Path("hdfspath:/user/abc");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fs.create(pt, true)));
        // TO append data to a file, use fs.append(Path f)
        fs.setReplication(new Path("hdfspath:/user/abc"), (short)3);
        String line;
        line = "This is Written to the File";
        System.out.println(line);
        br.write(line);
        br.close();

    }
    }
```

Please check for syntax as I have just typed the code here.

Comment: thank you it works,but it seems only works after the file exists.it means the point I save the file ,the replication factor is still 3, then the cluster will store 3 copys,after that I can chang the factor for this file to 2.

Comment: Its more like you are creating a file with the default configuration of your file system and then over-riding the configuration according to your wish. hope i clarified your doubt